# Login page in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a master page which needs to enabled only when the user provides proper credential in login page in WPF.

To be elaborate when user launches the application it should display login window upfront and master window behind it(it should be disabled).The master window should be enabled only when the user logs in with proper credentials.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can open login window as Dialog in event "loaded" of master window.

```
 Dim Obj_Wnd_Login As New <your login window>

Obj_Wnd_Login.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanx for the response makwana.

Comment: But as like windows form,WPF don't have a overriden method for ShowDialog( childform.ShowDialog(masterform)).So is there any alternative for this?

Comment: WPF window control has this Function by default. Declare a object of WPF window that you want to open as "Dim Obj_Wnd_Login As New <your login window>". then call function as   "Obj_Wnd_Login.ShowDialog()" Show dialog open a window and returns only newly opened window is closed.